# NullPointerException, AbstractHttpClient.class source not found

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I've downloaded an Android project and I'm using it as library for my own App. At the beginning, some errors right after adding this project to my workspace (signalled by an red exclamation sign, I'm using Eclipse by the way) saying some libraries were missing: `common-codec-1.4.jar`, `simple-xml-2.6.2.jar` and `common-logging-1.1.1.jar`. So I looked them up on the Internet and even though they were not the most updated ones, I downloaded them, added them to libs folder of this project and built the path, removing this way this exclamation sign.

Now, I am  trying this project from my App and when calling one of its methods, a NullPointerException is thrown. So while debugging, I stepped into every function to see where this exception was thrown. After several steps, I ran into a "Source not found" message for the class AbstractHttpClient. The import was done by

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient;
```

but there was no such library referenced at the project. Surprisingly, there was no error on this import and what's more: this function that throws this exception has two modes of operation, say that, and in one of them the exception isn't thrown, even though it follows the same path and I end up in the same "Source not found" message for the same class.

I've tried adding this library (http components by apache) but the error persists.

What do you think it's the problem or what else could I do to find out?

This is the printed Stack trace

```
01-22 12:03:30.706: I/Exception(5582): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-22 12:03:30.706: I/Exception(5582):  at de.aflx.sardine.impl.SardineImpl.list(SardineImpl.java:403)
01-22 12:03:30.706: I/Exception(5582):  at com.example.webdavsardinetest.MainActivity.isFolder(MainActivity.java:156)
01-22 12:03:30.706: I/Exception(5582):  at com.example.webdavsardinetest.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:72)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: look at lin 403 of  `SardineImpl` there must be the error.

Comment: You can look up specific classes and their packages on sites like jarfinder.

Comment: I know I know, in fact I downloaded the apache http components and it contains this class but anyway this message keeps showing up. And in any case, I do not understand why the exception it's thrown in one case, but not in the other. As I said, it calls the same methods in both cases...